# adding a legend in 3 for loops with three plots .MATLAB

Tags: plot, matlab-figure, legend, dynamic-data-display

l want to make a legend for my figure but l have 3 for loops with three plots like mentioned below :
 **legend 1 : essential   legend 2 : less essential legend 3 : most important**

```
for P=1:K
   % body 
plot(.....,'bo');
end

for  Z=N:T
  %body
plot(....,'ro'):
end

for  i=1:L
 %body
plot(....,'ko'):
end
```

how can l manage my legend ?
thank you